Import [dependency] could not be resolved despite downloading it (anaconda)?
Trying to import torch in a .ipynb script. torch 2.2.2 listed when I run conda list, but still won't import. What can I try? Running anaconda3. Env is (I think?) /Users/name/anaconda3. Working on VSCode btw with python 3.8
I tried going to the pyTorch website and running this command: conda install pytorch::pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch
Seemed to add a few things to the conda list, but did not solve the problem.
